# Ender 3 Random Axis Shift

Tags: creality-ender-3

My printer has been doing weird things lately.  It used to print fine, but now it's like the Y or X axis after a certain percentage time.
ie on a 24 hour print: it got off at 5 hours
on a 42 print it got off at 16%

Thoughts?

Comment: Good morning, and Welcome to the 3D Printing SE site.

Comment: I am sure what you are asking.  The best questions have lots of details in the questions, such as the type of printer, the material being printed, temperature settings if you have them, anything that might have changed, and, if at all possible, one or more pictures of the defect.

Answer (score 2):

The usual suspects are overheating stepper motor drivers and over-tight belts. It can also be caused by belts coming loose in their mounts.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems printing overnight using a computer and suspected network activity causing the problem.  Energy savings settings can also cause it.  I print overnight using an SD card to print the gcode file to solve the problem.